# Compute sum of counts using union

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS Cuenta FROM prerating_calculos 
WHERE usuario NOT LIKE 'TEST' AND usuario NOT LIKE 'ADMIN' 
UNION SELECT COUNT(id) AS Cuenta FROM prerating_calculos_apx 
WHERE usuario NOT LIKE 'TEST' AND usuario NOT LIKE 'ADMIN'
```

This is what it shows me

```
----------   
| Cuenta |
----------
|   1    |
----------
|   75   |
----------
```

This is what I want you to show me

```
----------   
| Cuenta |
----------
|   76   |
----------
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:php] tag because this is not a PHP question. If it does then please [edit] and explain why

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to implement a subselect, selecting the sum from your initial query.

```
SELECT SUM(Cuenta) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS Cuenta FROM prerating_calculos 
    WHERE usuario NOT LIKE 'TEST' AND usuario NOT LIKE 'ADMIN' 
    UNION SELECT COUNT(id) AS Cuenta FROM prerating_calculos_apx 
    WHERE usuario NOT LIKE 'TEST' AND usuario NOT LIKE 'ADMIN') AS T1
```